# (Grading system) Pressing calculate while leaving the grades textboxes empty shows format exception not handled

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently making a Grading system and I tried
to click the calculate button in order for grades to calculate but I tried it leaving blank and press calculate but the system crashes and says " formatException unhandled(input string was not in correct format).

I coded the if else statements to identify if it is null or empty but it doesn't work. These are my codes "(btw my textboxes are converted to double in order to let the user to input grades in double form

e.g `double seatwork = Convert.ToDouble(txtSeatworkScore.text);`

I'll make my code short. nvm the else statement.

```
        try
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSeatWorkScoreP.Text))
            {

                MessageBox.Show(" Input Seatwork for Prelim ");
                txtSeatWorkScoreP.Focus();
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSeatWorkScoreM.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Input Seatwork for Midterm ");
                txtSeatWorkScoreM.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                txtResultP.Text = finalgradep.ToString("0#.##%"); // display final grade of prelim
                txtResultM.Text = finalgradem.ToString("0#.##%"); // display final grade of midterm
                txtResultF.Text = finalgradef.ToString("0#.##%"); // display final grade of finals

                txtGA.Text = getga.ToString("0#.##%"); // display average
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException q)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Make sure to input all the scores " + q.Message);
        }
```

Comment: from where values for `finalgradep`,`finalgradem`,`finalgradef` are set?

Comment: Why dont you remove the try catch and find out which line is causing the error in debug mode ?

Answer (score 0):

try using something like "string newstring = string.Format("{0:0.00}",finalgradep);" and then txtResult.Text = newstring +"%";

also, be sure to use text changed events or key press events to filter your text boxes to receive only numeric input. you can achieve that by trying to parse the text in the box into an integer with a try/catch that tries to do a  int.Parse(txtSeatWorkScoreP.Text) upon keyup event in the text box, and then either reverts the text in the box to its previous state stored in a global string variable, or allows the entry of the new number and then updates your global string variable to reflect the new entry.

the error you are receiving is likely because you are trying to format information in a way that is unacceptable.

Comment: Hi ,I dont think that it answered my problem. My problem was if the user press the calculate button and leaving something empty or lets say all textboxes empty(e.g on quizzes textobox, seatwork texbox)It would prompt that something like this (" Cant calculate pls input quiz score ") But instead, the system goes down and direct me to the varibal and said format exception unhandled. btw i disabled the typing of any kind of letters or symbols on those textboxes, only integers are aloud.Anyway any idea how can i set specific range to each int boxes? ex. only allowed not exceeding 40 points? thanks

Comment: try adding an if statement like:

if (txtSeatWorkScoreP.Text == "")
{
MessageBox.Show("Please enter a score for SeatWorkScoreP!");
return;
}

but do one for each text box.  Maybe you cannot format an empty string.

you could use TextChanged events to check if the int.Parse(txtSeatWorkScoreP.Text) is in the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping. I already solved the problem by changing the formatexception to "Exception" to handle all kinds of exception, with that, if the textbox is blank, it would print " please input seatwork " something like that.

Thanks! happy coding :)